# src\debug-agent.cc:149: Assertion `(err) == (0)' failed

Tags: node.js, serverless, node-debugger

I get the above error trying to run node-debug. I'm using node-inspector v1.1.1 and node v6.10.0. 
A resolution for this matter is much needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error may imply, the error is caused by the compiler (.cc) going bizarre. Therefore, the error is caused when compiling. 
In my case was caused by a very lengthy resources URL of a stream function in the serverless file of the project. This therefore caused the java script heap to exceed and crash. The URL had to be reduced down and then it worked. 
The error doesn't have to do with NodeJS or Node Inspector or there version incompatibilities.